# SQL Query (SQLite3) on inner joins and SUM

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables with schema

```
CREATE TABLE City
  (
     City CHAR,
     Area INT
  )

CREATE TABLE Revenue
  (
     Municipality        CHAR,
     City_Code           CHAR,
     [Road tax]          INT,
     [Water Tax]         INT,
     [Entertainment Tax] INT
  )
```

I need to rank the top 3 cities in descending order of area while also printing the sum of the total tax obtained by the city. Something along the lines of (e.g.):

```
New York, 40
Chicago, 27
London, 30
```

City field from table City and City_code field from table Revenue need to to identify cities between the tables.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Try my code, this may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema doesn't make sense. There should be a common key in both your tables so that it becomes possible to fetch `CITY` name from `CITY` table by joining on the `CITY_CODE` column. I have made this assumption in the below query.

```
SELECT B.CITY, (A.ROAD_TAX + A.WATER_TAX + A.ENTERTAINMENT_TAX) AS TOTAL_TAX
FROM
REVENUE A 
INNER JOIN
CITY B
ON A.CITY_CODE = B.CITY_CODE
ORDER BY (A.ROAD_TAX + A.WATER_TAX + A.ENTERTAINMENT_TAX) DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
SELECT C.City,(R.[Road tax]+R.[Water Tax]+R.[Entertainment Tax])[Total Tax]
FROM City C
JOIN Revenue R ON R.CityCode=C.City
ORDER BY C.Area DESC
LIMIT 3;
```